# Background material: how to skip a page?

Tags: pdfpages, backgrounds

In the code below `\NoBgThispage` disables the background

1. only in the page where it is set, in the first occurrence (p. 1)
2. in the page where it is set and the remainder, in the second occurrence.

Why?

In the code below, among images A, B, C, I need only B, not to have a background, instead of B & C. How?

PS: The rational for selectively skipping `background`, in my situation, is that there are certain uses of `background` in which the background is hidden (`keyfig`), so I've been looking into skipping it and using watermark instead.

[Documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/background/background.pdf).

UPDATE The reason I'm not using watermark throughout is that over `includepdf`, there have been cases where typographic characters are messed up away from the watermark. I don't have an mwe. Instead, here's an actual example:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[
12pt
%,draft
]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}%-------------------------------------------------
\backgroundsetup{
  contents={\Huge\textbf{BACKGROUND}},
  angle=45,
  color=red!90,
%  vshift=130,
  opacity=1.0,
  scale=2.0
}
\NoBgThispage
\pagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\includepdf[pages={1}]{example-image-a.pdf}

\clearpage
\NoBgThispage
\includepdf[pages={1}]{example-image-b.pdf}

\clearpage
%\BgThispage 
\includepdf[pages={1}]{example-image-c.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: background uses afterpage to reset the background and this seems not work well with pdfpages.