# Two seemingly identical l3seq cause different behavior passed to function

Tags: xwatermark, l3prop, l3seq

I have two `seq`'s, one constructed from a `clist`, another from a `prop`, whose expansion (with `,` between items) look the same. They are supposed to contain options to `\newwatermark`. The use of a `prop` is to make sure there are no duplicate in the options (and other requirements). The first works as expected, the second fails to compile. Why, and how can it be fixed? I don't get this error with `includepdf` in place of `newwatermark`.

[image]
[image]

PS: this is a follow up to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584161/expandafter-issue).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xwatermark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn\__erw_pass_option:Nn{#1[#2]}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__erw_pass_option:Nn {Ne}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn\l__Foo_tl{angle=45, scale=0.15}
%\tl_set:Nn\l__Baz_tl{page=\thepage,xpos=-20}
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__a_seq{page=\thepage,xpos=-20}
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__prop{page=\thepage,xpos=-20}
\seq_new:N \l__b_seq
\prop_map_inline:Nn \l__prop{\seq_put_right:Nn\l__b_seq{#1=#2}}

a:\seq_use:Nn \l__a_seq{,}\\
b:\seq_use:Nn \l__b_seq{,}.

\newpage
\__erw_pass_option:Ne \newwatermark{\seq_use:Nn\l__a_seq {,}}{DRAFT} % OK
%\__erw_pass_option:Ne \newwatermark{\seq_use:Nn\l__b_seq {,}}{DRAFT} %File ended while scanning use of \xwm@
\__erw_pass_option:Ne \includepdf{\l__Foo_tl}{example-image-a}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use the xwatermark package. It uses catoptions, and this is incompatible with a current latex.

Comment: You’ve been advised several times about the proper conventions on names for variables.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, what's a good replacement for `xwatermark`, `background`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It was pointed out here `bakground` and `pdfpages` may clash. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556935/background-material-how-to-skip-a-page#comment1404329_556935

Comment: @egreg, I fixed that, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequences are not the same because, in the sequence constructed via the property list, the keys are converted to `str` (that is to say strings of `expl3`). The catcodes of the tokens are not the same.

As said in the documentation `interface3.pdf`:

> A TEX string (and thus an expl3 string) is a series of characters
> which have category code 12 (“other”) with the exception of space
> characters which have category code 10 (“space”). Thus at a technical
> level, a TEX string is a token list with the appropriate category
> codes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { key = smth }

  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { key = smth }

  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { #1 = #2 } }

  \tl_set:Nf \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { } }
  \tl_set:Nf \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { } }

  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl { TRUE } { FALSE } % return FALSE
}

--

{
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { key }

  \exp_args:NNx \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \l_tmpa_str = smth }

  \exp_args:NNx \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { \l_tmpa_str = smth }

  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { #1 = #2 } }

  \tl_set:Nf \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { } }
  \tl_set:Nf \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { } }

  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl { TRUE } { FALSE } % return TRUE
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The first part of that code corresponds to your programmation and the result is FALSE. In the second case, keys are yet strings by construction and the result is TRUE.

Comment: This identifies where my code fails, but does not solve the problem, so I reframed the problem here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584690/keepin-key-value-pairs-in-l3prop-in-a-way-that-preserves-catcode